# Cursor Based Pagination and detecting changes in Real-Time data for offline first applications

Tags: design-patterns, pagination, real-time, offline-caching

in a blog with infinite scroll, client side will query server for posts

example max_id = 0, min_id=0. server will answer with latest 30 record `[id:1000,999,998 etc..,970]`.

now next request from client will ask for `max_id=1000&min_id=970`, server will answer with 30 more posts that has ids > 1000 or lesser than 970.
if there is no newer posts that 1000, then normal reply will be id 970-940.

this is implemented in an infinite scroll. and for offline-first app, all posts are saved client side and presented next time user visit.

now next time user open app, it will show posts `max_id=1000&min_id=930` and will get any new posts or fetch more older posts, but **there is no way it can detect a change in one of the posts that it already have in client side. **

say post id=999 was updated by user. only way to get this update would be to requery server for all posts as if there is no cached posts. i feel that this is a waste of band since 99% of times there will be no updates, so there was no need for this over fetching.

is there a design pattern that tackle this point in offline-first applications ?

Answer (score 0):

let's assume a scenario:

1. user fetch posts from server
2. app cached fetched posts  3 -
3. user left the app
4. user back and app shows cached posts while
   loading from server
5. user took action on a cached post here u
   can check the post and **return a warning if something changed before executing the action**.